# Getting PDFTK installed on Heroku 18 for use in my Laravel app

Tags: laravel, heroku, pdftk

I have added this `pdftk` buildpack to my free app on Heroku: https://github.com/fxtentacle/heroku-pdftk-buildpack.git.

I am unable to deploy my application to Heroku:

```
Preparing runtime environment...
-----> Checking for additional extensions to install...
-----> heroku-pdftk-buildpack app detected
cp: cannot stat 'binaries-heroku-18/*': No such file or directory
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile heroku-pdftk-buildpack app.
 !     Push failed
```

Also, I have added `heroku/php` and set the index of this buildpack to 1. When I go to my app's temporary URL, Laravel runs, but for some reasons, `pdftk` doesn't seem to run. Has anybody faced the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

That buildpack hasn't been updated for the `heroku-18` stack. Its `compile` script tries to [copy precompiled binaries](https://github.com/fxtentacle/heroku-pdftk-buildpack/blob/7dcad0bed3392ad6baadcb557c1c2f2526d89fb9/bin/compile#L6) from `binaries-$STACK/` into `/app/bin/`, but only contains binary directories for `cedar-14` and `heroku-16`.

You could [roll your app back to `heroku-16`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-apps-stacks-set-stack), which will be [supported until April, 2021](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-16-stack#support-period), but of course this will also change other package versions:

```
heroku apps:stacks:set heroku-16 --app myapp
```

This would be very similar to going from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 16.04, but it's likely to be your simplest solution.

Alternatively, you could fork the `pdftk` buildpack you found and update it for Ubuntu 18.04, but that isn't likely to be straightforward.

`pdftk` was removed from Ubuntu's official repositories [because it depends on a deprecated library called `gcj`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028983/242096). The buildpack you're trying to use includes `libgcj` for `cedar-14` and `heroku-16` in their respective binary directories. You'll have to include that as well if you want to update the buildpack.

---

> Also, I have added `heroku/php` and set the index of this buildpack to 1. When I go to my app's temporary URL, Laravel runs, but for some reasons, `pdftk` doesn't seem to run. Has anybody faced the same issue?

The error you're seeing is preventing your application from being deployed. You're not seeing a new version of the application with `pdftk`, but whatever was last deployed successfully. You'll have to resolve the build issue before you can use `pdftk`.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this article (http://derekbarber.ca/blog/2014/11/20/using-pdftk-with-rails-on-heroku/) and got PDFTK working on Heroku-18, though on a Rails app.

Code excerpted below, HT @derek-barber.

```
mkdir -p [my_project]/vendor/pdftk/lib [my_project]vendor/pdftk/bin
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/millie/pdftk-source.git
cd pdftk-source
tar xzvf pdftk.tar.gz
mv bin/pdftk [my_project]/vendor/pdftk/bin/
mv lib/libgcj.so.12 [my_project]/vendor/pdftk/lib/
cd [my_project]
git add -f vendor/pdftk/
git commit -m "Add pdftk dependencies"
git push heroku master
heroku config:set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib:/app/vendor/pdftk/lib
heroku config:set PATH=/app/.heroku/python/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/app/vendor/p
```

Answer (score 0):

Once this PR is merged: https://github.com/fxtentacle/heroku-pdftk-buildpack/pull/9 then the buildpack should work with heroku-18 stack.

Maybe leave a comment to the repo owner asking them to merge?

---

For now, you could use the forked & updated version: https://github.com/Aesthetikx/heroku-pdftk-buildpack which works with heroku-18 stack.

If you are using an `app.json` file, then point the pdftk buildpack to the forked version:

```
  "buildpacks": [
    ...,
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/fxtentacle/heroku-pdftk-buildpack.git"
    }
  ]
```